# Capybara's fill_in and special characters

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, aem

Am executing the following test with Capybara against a web-application using the Selenium driver

```
visit 'mypage.html'
click_button('login')
fill_in('Name', :with => 'test_user')
fill_in('Password', :with => 'oq36bxW6~V/X%U*x')
```

Whereas the combination of username and password is correct, am getting back an error that the combination is wrong.

Now, when I change the password to something simple, e.g. "admin", everything works fine.

So I assume it might have something to do with the special characters, but have not found a solution, yet.

All hints are welcome. Thanks a lot!

BTW: Not testing against a rails app, but against AEM 5.6.1 if that information might help.

Answer (score 0):

Slashes aren't valid characters for URL component strings. If you run it through [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), you'll see the output changes.

`oq36bxW6~V/X%U*x` becomes `oq36bxW6~V%2FX%25U*x`

Comment: you removed the slash and it still fails? can I see the object you've built before logging in?

Comment: yes, ran it through the encoder you provided. no luck.